# Gitlab ci/cd -Cannot retrieve pipeline status error

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a requirement to do git pull on server when new files or changes pushed to Master.
After creating merge request to push files from Developmenet --> Master, and the merge request is accepted, I could see the error

```
"Could not retrieve the pipeline status. For troubleshooting steps, read the documentation."
```

```
variables:
  GIT_DEPTH: 0
testing:
  stage: test

  script:
    - cd /staging/Repository
    - git pull origin master

  only:
    - master
```

Can anyone please help me in resolving the error. I did not find clear solution to this issue in any forums.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your gitlab-runner. What runner are you using?

Comment: I'm using shared gitlab runner with version gitlab-runner 13.8.0